# How to replace string using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, string

**How to check a string and replace the space into "_" ?**

```
let str = "hello @%123abc456:nokibul amin mezba jomadder% @%123abc456:nokibul% @%123abc456:nokibul amin mezba%"

str = str.replace(regex, 'something');

console.log(str);

// Output: str = "hello @%123abc456:nokibul_amin_mezba_jomadder% @%123abc456:nokibul% @%123abc456:nokibul_amin_mezba%"
```

Please help me out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check this out. I think it's gonna help**

Hints:

1. `/:(\w+\s*)+/g` Separates the `:nokibul amin mezba jomadder` as a group.
2. Replace the group with index-wise templating `{0}`, `{1}` ... `{n}`.
3. Mapping the groups. Ex: `:nokibul amin mezba jomadder` to `:nokibul_amin_mezba_jomadder`.
4. Finally, replacing the templates `{index}` with groups.

```js
let str = "hello @%123abc456:nokibul amin mezba jomadder% @%123abc456:nokibul% @%123abc456:nokibul amin mezba%";
/* Extracting Groups */
let groups = str.match(/:(\w+\s*)+/g);

/* Formatting Groups: Replacing Whitespaces with _ */
let userTags = groups.map((tag, index) => {
  /* Index wise string templating */
  str = str.replace(tag, `{${index}}`)
  return tag.replace(/\s+/g, "_");
});

console.log(str);
console.log(userTags);

/* Replacing string templates with group values */
userTags.forEach((tag, index) => str = str.replace(`{${index}}`, tag));

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can use https://regex101.com/ to test whether a regex works, it supports substitution as well.

Regex being used: `(\w+)[ ]`, to grep all words between space, and use `$1_` to substitute the space to underscore.

```js
const regex = /(\w+)[ ]/gm;
const str = `Input: str="nokibul" output: str="nokibul"

Input: str="nokibul amin" Output: str="nokibul_amin"

Input: str="nokibul amin mezba" Output: str="nokibul_amin_mezba"

Input: str="nokibul amin mezba jomadder" Output: str="nokibul_amin_mezba_jomadder"`;

const subst = `$1_`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

Comment: Can Please edit your regex pattern Little bit. Because I updated my formate. :)

Answer (score 1):

Simple one liner

`str.replace(/:[^%]*%/g, arg => arg.replace(/ /g, '_'))`

**Explanation:**

`/:[^%]*%/g` Find all occurrences starting with `:` and ending at `%`

This will return patterns like this `:nokibul amin mezba jomadder%` `:nokibul%` `:nokibul amin mezba%`

Next is to replace all space characters with underscores using this `replace(/ /g, '_')`